# How do I stub a class method with a class_double in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I’m trying to write a simple isolated test for a controller method in my Rails 4 app. The method takes an ID from a query string, asks the `Project` model to give me some rows from the persistence layer, and render the result as JSON.

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def projects_for_company
    render json: Project.for_company(params[:company_id])
  end

end
```

I’m struggling with stubbing the `for_company` method. Here is the code I’m trying:

```
require "rails_helper"

describe ProjectsController do

  describe "GET #projects_for_company" do

    it "returns a JSON string of projects for a company" do
      dbl = class_double("Project")
      project = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:project)
      allow(dbl).to receive(:for_company).and_return([project])
      get :projects_for_company
      expect(response.body).to eq([project].to_json)
    end

  end

end
```

Since I’ve stubbed the `for_company` method, I expect the implementation of the method to be ignored. However, if my model looks like this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.for_company(id)
    p "I should not be called"
  end

end
```

…Then I can see that `I should not be called` is actually printed to the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Question to earlier self: What were you even trying to do? Looks like you actually wanted to say `allow(Project).to receive(:for_company) { [project] }`…

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`class_double` doesn't actually replace the constant. You can call `as_stubbed_const` to replace the original

```
class_double("Project").as_stubbed_const
```

This is the just a convenience wrapper around `stub_const`

Comment: Wow. I spent hours struggling with this. The docs are very unclear about this point! Thanks